# How to store/save path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a small PowerShell snippet that fits perfectly for my needs. My knowledge about PowerShell is limited.

I have this:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\j.doe\Desktop\Test Stage EDIT\Source" -Include *.xlsx -Recurse
ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    Import-Excel -Path $File.FullName | Export-Csv ($file.FullName -replace '\.xlsx$', '.csv') -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Which it take from $files folder every *.xlsx and convert to *.csv with the same name as well. So the point now is I want to export the *.csv files to another folder and not in the same where *.xlsx located.

I have try to add -Path or in another way the .saveAs without any result. What can I try next?

Comment: Maybe something like this in for loop: `$CsvFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath ($File.BaseName + ".csv")
    Import-Excel -Path $File.FullName | Export-Csv -Path $CsvFileName -NoTypeInformation`
Make destination folder variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you have to do is to make full path to destination folder and set that as destination path for exporting `.csv` file. You can do it by joining path to destination folder and name of current file that you are moving.

Something like this works for me:

```
Import-Module ImportExcel

$SourceFolder = "..."
$DestinationFolder = "..."

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse

ForEach ($File in $Files) {
    $CsvFileName = Join-Path -Path $DestinationFolder -ChildPath ($File.BaseName + ".csv")
    Import-Excel -Path $File.FullName | Export-Csv -Path $CsvFileName -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate! It works fine for me. Let me ask something more if it's not problem. This can I make to run automatically with windows scheduler every X time, correct?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, I'm not really familiar with that topic, but it's not hard for me to believe that it's possible and I dare say, probably easy to implement. This is the first link I bumped into, it looks fine: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/create-scheduled-task-for-powershell-script.html#:~:text=Open%20Task%20Scheduler%20%3E%3E%20Create%20a,0%5Cpowershell.exe%E2%80%9D.

Comment: Milos, any suggestion about encoding issues? I'm facing encoding troubles in Greek Language in the *.csv.

Comment: Is it fine in Excel files?

Comment: You can check out this link: https://community.spiceworks.com/t/export-csv-encoding-utf8-exports-as-utf-8-bom/599623
There are some following links there you may want to check out.
This is from docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4#-encoding
If your Excel files are not UTF-8 encoded, I'm not sure how it will reflect on csv files.

Comment: I just tried adding `-Encoding UTF8`. I added Greek letters to my Excel file. After converting if I open `.csv` file with Excel, I get some gibberish, but if I open it with notepad, all is well.

Comment: When I add the "-Encoding UTF8" after the "-NoTypeInformation" the CSV is perfect! Milos I have to thank you for all your help that I have receive today from you! If you ever visit Greece let me buy you a beer! I mean it! :) :) :)

Comment: Hahah I'm glad to be of some service. Btw, since I'm from Serbia, there is a chance that I go to Greece sometime for summer vacation so I will remember your offer :) .

Comment: on a minor note: I suggesto to add the `-File` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`: it will make the script a bit more efficient(which is probably not too relevant in this specific instance) and safe as it will automatically skip the directories... included directories that might have names ending in `.xlsx`